# l have an error in my java mysql update syntax .any one can correct

Tags: java

This is my sql query

```
String ss="UPDATE bookindates SET 1=" xy[1] ",2=" xy[2] " WHERE carno='" cn "' and(month=" mn " and year=" yr ")";
```

l got an error message like the following

> "you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1=0,2=O' at line one "

Comment: it should be `update set columnName1=value1, columnName2=value2 where ...`, you on the other hand you got `1=vlaue1, 2=value2` ...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ' ' for the column of the tables, mysql is taking then as number not column names

here is an example

```
UPDATE lineup_accounting.test 
SET '1' = 1 , '2' = 2 
WHERE id = 1231
```